# Drawing Android progress bar with shadow at outside of progress area

Tags: android

I am facing issues when creating an Android progress bar for which there is shadow in progress area. I need the progress bar as below.

[image]

Comment: post your code please?

Comment: I have attached of progress bar (how it should look).

Comment: Did you sort this out?